# Flexbox row among themselves

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using CSS flexbox to create a vertical centered navigation:

```
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

The child elements should stay among themselves. For now the elements are vertical centered but they stay next to each other. Is there a fancy solution or some workaround for doing that? Notice that the flex-direction is set to `row`.

The result should look like this:

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYuCP.png)

Check it out:

```css
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="contact-info">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4d58xrz8/

Comment: What you mean by *they stay next to each other* ?

Comment: `display: flex` on `ul`?

Comment: Could you add an image of the layout you're aiming for? Or be more specific, thanks

Comment: The "Lorem Ipsum" is placed next to the navigation. But these elements should be among each other. I'll post an image.

Comment: Please explain what the end result must be. This is pretty vague

Comment: apparently you meant *below*  each other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-direction:column;` to your `#main-nav`

```css
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: left;
  padding: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="contact-info">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, `flex-direction` is what you need, and replace `align-items` by `justify-content`, because the direction changes.

Edit you css like this to obtain your result :

```
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding: 50px;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```